# Rigging A Characters Created w/ Mirror Modifier

Tags: rigging, armature, mirror-modifier

I have an existing human model that I tried to rig. I created the character using a mirror modifier. I then added an armature to the character but bc of the mirror modifier my model moves the mirrored side of the image to an unintended pose. Do I need to mirror the bones also? How do I fix this? See attached screen recording of the rigged model.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13eRBVQG9KwdJJQSg_8QidTHd6kRaSYqk/view?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you pleas share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Done. I placed the link below the image.

Answer (score 1):

You have kept a *Mirror* modifier, you can but in that case you need your bones to be correctly named, meaning the left arm needs to be called arm_L or arm.L, right arm needs to be called arm_R or arm.R and so on, then reparent.

Comment: Did it work on your end? It's not working on my end.

Comment: yes it works for me

Comment: Please send the file

Comment: sure, here it is, of course you need to reparent after renaming, also apply the scale of both armature and object before parenting: https://blend-exchange.com/b/oVsJz44S

Comment: It works! Thank you, you saved me a lot of time and headaches.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is a way to separately move the bones of a mirrored character simply bc the purpose of the mirror action is to replicate the changes of a single side. However, I was able to properly repose my model by 1) removing the mirror modifier from my model and then 2) creating bones on the half (or remaining side) of my character. I re-added the modifier thereafter and was able to put my model into t-pose without the arms moving to that weird position.
To move the character into other poses, the only solution that I can think of is to remove the mirror modifier, duplicate the half, combine the two meshes, and then add the armature.

[image]